# some one help me, i cant get value from database when edit filed to select

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have create a select option form but when edit i can get current value from database.

```
 <select name="t_proyek_kd_proyek" id="t_proyek_kd_proyek" class="select-search"  />
        <option value=""></option>
        <?php 
        $t_cost=$this->db->query("select * from t_proyek ");

        foreach($t_cost->result() as $value){
          $selected= '';
          if($nm_proyek == $value->nm_proyek){
            $selected = 'selected';

          }
        ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $value->kd_proyek; ?>" <?php echo $selected;?>>
            <?php echo $value->nm_proyek; ?>
          </option>
       <?php }?>

      </select>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please explain what the problem you're facing? Piece of code doesn't help us to know the problem/issue.

Comment: i cant get value from database when edit filed to select combobox

Comment: took filed from the database to display to the combobox when the edit data

Comment: sory my languange so bad

Answer (score 0):

You should not use value for select tag. Check the condition in inside the option tag and make it is selected like following

```
<select name="t_proyek_kd_proyek" id="t_proyek_kd_proyek" class="select-search"  placeholder="Pilih..." />
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php 
    $t_cost=$this->db->query("select * from t_proyek ");
    foreach($t_cost->result() as $value){?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value->kd_proyek; ?>" <?php if($nm_proyek==$value->kd_proyek) { ?> selected="selected" <?php }?> ><?php echo $kd_proyek=$value->nm_proyek; ?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

Comment: Assign the database value in the nm_proyek variable

Comment: i have'd tried variable $nm_proyek = '';

but still not get value

Comment: You should not provide as empty value. Before the form select previous value from database and store in variable $nm_proyek.

Comment: can u tell me how to do that

Comment: Refer this following link, how to add,edit,delete values from database http://www.2my4edge.com/2014/12/basic-insert-view-edit-delete-and.html

Comment: now i have problem the last record selected when edit record from database

Comment: what are the table fields?

Comment: field 'nm_proyek'
this my code
' <select name="t_proyek_kd_proyek" id="t_proyek_kd_proyek" class="select-search" value="<?php echo $nm_proyek; ?> "  placeholder="Pilih..." />
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php 
    $nm_proyek = '';
    $t_cost=$this->db->query("select * from t_proyek ");
    foreach($t_cost->result() as $value){?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value->kd_proyek; ?>" selected="selected"  <?php if($nm_proyek==$value->kd_proyek)  { ?>  <?php }?> ><?php echo $kd_proyek=$value->nm_proyek; ?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>'

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <?php 
> $conn = new mysqli('SERVER NAME', 'DB USER NAEM', 'DB USER PASSWORD', 'DB NAME');
> // Check connection
> if ($conn->connect_error) {
>     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
> }
> //set the value of which option you want to selected
> $nm_proyek = '';
> ?>
> <!-- for combobox  you should use 'multiple' -->
> <select name="t_proyek_kd_proyek" id="t_proyek_kd_proyek" class="select-search" placeholder="Pilih..." multiple />
>     <option value=""></option>
>     <?php
>     $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `t_proyek`");
>     while($value = $query->fetch_object()) {?>
>         <option value="<?php echo $value->kd_proyek; ?>" <?php $nm_proyek == $value->kd_proyek ? "selected='selected'" : "" ?> ><?php echo $kd_proyek=$value->nm_proyek; ?></option>
>     <?php }?>
> </select>
> ```

Comment: still not get value

Comment: - is db connection good?
- debug $query variable.
- inspect your browse and then try to reload, is any clue available there.

Comment: i think is good, my record (nm_proyek) has show in combobox, but when edit cant get curent value from database or has blank on combobox...

Comment: you should set the value in this $nm_proyek variable which one you want to keep selected during edit. did you do that?

Comment: '<select name="t_proyek_kd_proyek" id="t_proyek_kd_proyek" class="select-search"  placeholder="Pilih..." />
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php 
    $nm_proyek = '';
    $t_cost=$this->db->query("select * from t_proyek ");
    foreach($t_cost->result() as $value){?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value->kd_proyek; ?>" <?php if($nm_proyek==$value->kd_proyek) { ?> selected="selected" <?php }?> ><?php echo $kd_proyek=$value->nm_proyek; ?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>'

Comment: this my model

'function update($id, $data)
    {
        $this->db->where($this->id, $id);
        $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
    }'

Comment: this is my bottom edit

'<li><a href="<?php echo site_url() ?>konsultan/cost/ubah/<?php echo $cost->kd_cost;?>" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-popup="tooltip" title="Ubah" ><i class="icon-pencil text-warning-300"></i></a></li>'