# i cant get value from database when edit filed to select

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have create a select option form but when edit i can get current value from

```
<select name="t_proyek_kd_proyek" id="t_proyek_kd_proyek" class="select-search" value="<?php echo $nm_proyek; ?>" placeholder="Pilih..." />
<option value=""></option>
    <?php 
        $t_cost=$this->db->query("select * from t_proyek ");
        foreach($t_cost->result() as $value){?>
            <option value="<?php echo $value->kd_proyek; ?>" selected="selected">
            <?php echo $kd_proyek=$value->nm_proyek; ?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

Comment: you'll probably need to share how the data goes from the DB to `$t_cost`, and what `$t_cost->result()` does.

Comment: $t_cost->result() for show data from DB

Comment: @IPungPheīyngKhæ : You didn't responded to the answer given below?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [some one help me, i cant get value from database when edit filed to select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38046868/some-one-help-me-i-cant-get-value-from-database-when-edit-filed-to-select)

Comment: sory if possible duplicate, i m just try to fix my problem...

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="t_proyek_kd_proyek" id="t_proyek_kd_proyek" class="select-search"  />
  <option value=""></option>
  <?php 
  $t_cost=$this->db->query("select * from t_proyek ");

  foreach($t_cost->result() as $value){
    $selected= "";
    if($nm_proyek == $value->nm_proyek){
      $selected = 'selected';
    }
  ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $value->kd_proyek; ?>" <?php echo $selected;?>>
      <?php echo $value->nm_proyek; ?>
    </option>
 <?php }?>

</select>
```

Put `if()` condition on each `<option></option>` .

`$nm_proyek` in `if` condition is used which you wrote in `value` of `<select>`.

[**Note** : `value` & `placeholder` attribute are not there for `select` tag]

`<select>` tag attributes

- autofocus (new in HTML5)
- disabled
- form (new in HTML5)
- multiple
- name
- required (new in HTML5)
- size

So, remove `value` and `placeholder` from `<select>` tag.

For more info, click [select tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)

Comment: Where is your database value for dropdown to match in list @IPungPheīyngKhæ